# Factor Level issues after filling data frame using match

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I am using two large data files, each having `>2m` records. The sample data frames are

```
x <- data.frame("ItemID" = c(1,2,1,1,3,4,2,3,4,1), "SessionID" = c(111,112,111,112,113,114,114,115,115,115), "Avg" = c(1.0,0.45,0.5,0.5,0.46,0.34,0.5,0.6,0.10,0.15),"Category" =c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
y <- data.frame("ItemID" = c(1,2,3,4,3,4,5,7),"Category" = c("1","0","S","120","S","120","512","621"))
```

I successfully filled the `x$Category` using following command

```
x$Category <- y$Category[match(x$ItemID,y$ItemID)]
```

but

```
x$Category
```

gave me

```
[1] 1   0   1   1   S   120 0   S   120 1  
Levels: 0 1 120 512 621 S
```

In `x` there are only four distinct categories but the `Levels` shows six. Similarly, the frequency shows me `512` and `621` with `0` frequency. I am using the same data for classification where it shows six classes instead of four which effects the f measure and recall etc. negatively.

```
table(x$Category)
0   1 120 512 621   S 
2   4   2   0   0   2
```

while I want

```
table(x$Category)
0   1 120  S 
2   4   2  2
```

I tried merge [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146967/efficient-alternatives-to-merge-for-larger-data-frames-r) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768914/how-to-fill-data-frames-in-a-manner-dependent-on-values-in-other-rows-and-column) with a number of other questions but it is giving me an error message. I found here [Practical limits of R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5233769/practical-limits-of-r-data-frame/5234293#5234293) that it is the limitation of R.

Comment: does the function droplevels() save your problem?

Comment: Maybe `as.character(y$Category)[match(x$ItemID,y$ItemID)]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you, it worked. Although I tried to convert it to character but No working.
If you can add it as answer, I will will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

I would omit the Category column from your x data.frame, since it seems to only be serving as a placeholder until values from the y data.frame are filled in. Then, you can use left_join from dplyr with ItemID as the key variable, followed by droplevels() as suggested by TingITangIBob.

This gets you close, but my table does not exactly match yours:

```
dplyr::select(x, -Category) %>%
dplyr::left_join(y, by = "ItemID") %>%
droplevels()
```

0   1 120   S

2   4   4   4

I think this may have to do with the repeat ItemIDs in x?

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned, join and merge are not working with my dataset. It always crash at some level.